# Does YouTube Api allow showing custom ads before the YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube-api

We would like to display YouTube videos published by Universal Pictures Germany using the [MediaElementJs Player](https://www.mediaelementjs.com/). The player has a plugin for showing ads based on the VAST format.

Does YouTube allow showing custom ads before playing YouTube videos?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. But if that Video has Preroll it will also play after playing your VAST.

If you are using Video from "Universal Pictures Germany", you need to check their policy, If they don't mind you can display VAST Preroll.

Here you are using YouTube API to display video and using MediaElement.js Plugin for VAST. So technically MediaElement.js Player will play VAST not YouTube.

Comment: I mean is it allowed by YouTube's terms of service?

Comment: If you are using Video from "Universal Pictures Germany", you need to check their policy, If they don't mind you can display VAST Preroll.